# How to extract core values for summary() with a data frame?

Tags: r, summary, xtable

Basically looking to extract all the values from `summary(dataframe)` so that it can be used more efficiently with `xtable::xtable(summary(dataframe))`. In essence, I don't want to have to go and delete all the text (min, 1st quartile, ...). I just want to extract the matrix of values, my row titles would be in a latex table.

What I currently have is

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(rnorm(4*100), nrow = 100)
summary(X)

       V1                V2                 V3                  V4         
 Min.   :-2.2147   Min.   :-1.91436   Min.   :-2.888921   Min.   :-2.5923  
 1st Qu.:-0.4942   1st Qu.:-0.65105   1st Qu.:-0.455149   1st Qu.:-0.4954  
 Median : 0.1139   Median :-0.17722   Median :-0.001606   Median : 0.0247  
 Mean   : 0.1089   Mean   :-0.03781   Mean   : 0.029673   Mean   : 0.0516  
 3rd Qu.: 0.6915   3rd Qu.: 0.50090   3rd Qu.: 0.698491   3rd Qu.: 0.7453  
 Max.   : 2.4016   Max.   : 2.30798   Max.   : 2.649167   Max.   : 1.9713
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
     V1       V2        V3           V4         
 -2.2147   -1.91436  -2.888921   -2.5923  
 -0.4942   -0.65105   -0.455149   -0.4954  
  0.1139   -0.17722   -0.001606   0.0247  
  0.1089   -0.03781    0.029673   0.0516  
  0.6915    0.50090    0.698491   0.7453  
  2.4016    2.30798    2.649167   1.9713
```

When I try subsetting `X`, I just get the text included

cheers :-)

Comment: `apply(X, 2, summary)`

Comment: @RonakShah nice one :-)